# APP_INITIALIZER, resolve data during bootstrap

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 4.3 application, the goal that I am trying to achieve is resolve some data before any content on the page is displayed from bootstrap, and if there is an erorr re-direct to somewhere else, outside the application using location.assign();

I have tried APP_INITIALIZERS however, it does not detect the error message.

My Code:

```
    pvqFlowInit(): any {
    console.log('4176-21 Calling PVQ FLOW SERVICE!');
    // getData{{ deadLinePassed = true || false, flow = "CREATE || UPDATE", previousScreen = "/RBCXpress || /previousScreen" }}
    let response: PvqResponse = pvqStepUpResponseMerged;

    return this._http
        .get('Faked a URL for Error')
        .toPromise()
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

handleError(error: any) {
    console.log('ERROR OCCURED!');
    location.assign('https://www.google.com');
    console.log('REDIRECT!');
    return error;
}
```

My AppModule:

```
providers: [
PVQ_SERVICES,
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HeadersInterceptor, multi: true },
{
  // Provider for APP_INITIALIZER
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: bootstrapPvqService,
  deps: [PVQStepUpService],
  multi: true
},
pvqGuards
]

export function bootstrapPvqService(pvqStepUpService: PVQStepUpService): 
   Function {
    console.log('Calling SERVICE!!');
    return () => pvqStepUpService.pvqFlowInit();
}
```

For what I am trying to achieve, would it be better to just make a call during the bootstrap within main.ts and then pass any resolved data, etc? Or can this be achieved using APP_INITIALIZERS?

Comment: 1) You need `APP_INITIALIZER` if you need dependency injection from your project (and you actually use `PVQStepUpService` in your code). 2) APP_INITIALIZER accepts only `Promise`, so you need properly adjust your code...

Comment: I've changed it to be a promise, however -- I still see header and footer content before the page redirects to google.